# How to read sentence in vb

Tags: vb.net

How do I read a sentence in vb.net from textbox, split it to words, and store it in array? And how do I recombine it again? I would like to use a search or select function.

Comment: If you can't be bothered with researching and trying your hand at it - why should we?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "sentence" is a array of words, seperated with " "...

To split the "sentence" into an array of words:

```
  Dim words() As String = Split("Hello world, this is a test.", " ")
```

Word-Array back to "sentence"

```
Dim sentence As String
For each itm in words.items
sentence = sentence & " " & itm.toString
Next
sentence = Trim(Sentence)
```

Comment: `Dim sentence As String = String.Join(" ", words)` ;)